# Java variable arguments and rhino

Tags: java, arguments, rhino

I'm trying to put all my Java methods accessible from a javascript script.

As I want "shortcuts", I followed the following guide: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19197130/2897090 . But when my Java method has variable arguments, I'm not able to "expose" the method to use with javascript language.

```
public void printf(String format, Object... args) {
    out.printf(format, args);
}
//Gives org.mozilla.javascript.EvaluatorException: Unsupported parameter type "[Ljava.lang.Object;" in method printf
```

Other thing:

If i try to make a "shortcut to the `printf` using just "javascript":

```
function printf(format){
    java.lang.System.out.printf(format, arguments);
}
```

If I type anything, I get `org.mozilla.javascript.Arguments@NNNNNN`. How to fix that?

Thank you.

## Update

As I didn't find any solution, I changed the approach: now I'm just using the ScriptEngine. Practically what I'm doing is exposing the whole object (not just functions). Unfortunately every time that I need to call a function I need to prefix it with the name of the object that I've exposed.

Anyway, with that I could create my Java methods with variable arguments and use them without any modification on the JavaScript side.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this same problem.  Since then they've updated the documentation on what a FunctionObject could be.  It can only take a small set of data.  Here was my solution:

```
@JSFunction
public void log(Object messages) {
    if(messages instanceof  List) {
        console.log(((List)messages).toArray());
    }
    else if (messages instanceof Object[]) {
        console.log(((Object[])messages));
    }
    else {
        console.log(new Object[]{messages});
    }
}
```

I wanted it to take an array of objects to print out.  Instead I had to take an object, then use reflection to figure out if it was a list, array, or single object at runtime and provide appropriate handling.